# Unable to trim the string & get substring within same statement

Tags: c#, .net, string, substring

I am fetching a string from database which has length from 80k to 90K characters.

I want to remove all the leading `white-spaces` & get a `substring` of around 50k characters & store it into a `StringBuilder` as i have to pass this as parameter to another function.

**Code:**

```
StringBuider sb = new StringBuilder(dr["str"].ToString().TrimStart().SubString(0,50000));
```

But I am getting following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Index and length must refer to a location
>   within the string.

It's assured that even after trimming, string will have more than 50k characters.

If i do the trimming first & then get the substring then it works fine.
What could be the reason behind it? Can't `substring()`  perform on string that coming on the fly?

Comment: Don't assume, when you debugged and inspected the string after trimming did it have 50k+ characters? Substring doesn't think so.

Comment: `dr["str"].ToString().TrimStart().Take(50000)`

Comment: What do you think happens if you ask for the first 50,000 characters of a string that is 40,000 characters long? What is the value of `new StringBuilder(dr["str"].ToString().TrimStart().Length`?

Comment: Maybe that is not the real code because it wouldn't even compile(`Substring` instead `SubString`)

Comment: You are mistaken @HarshilDoshi.

Comment: This is a circular argument. You are claiming your input is > 50K characters. This is not true. if you wish to continue this discussion further, please share the value of `new StringBuilder(dr["str"].ToString().TrimStart().Length`. Don't guess, don't discuss, don't hypothesise. Run the code, get the value and share it.

Comment: If you can produce a minimal, complete and verifiable demonstration of SubString behaving incorrectly I'll buy a hat just to eat it.

Comment: Execute this in your database: `SELECT ColumnName FROM TableName WHERE LEN(LTRIM(ColumnName)) <= 50000`. I'm pretty sure that it returns something.

Comment: " It's assured that even after trimming, string will have more than 50k characters."
In my experience even if it's assured, best practices are to validate your data before executing code on it.

Answer (score 4):

It seems not all strings' `Length` in this table are `>= 50000`(at least not after `TrimStart`). If a string is shorter you get this exception. This is safer, more readable and more efficient:

```
string str = dr["str"].ToString().TrimStart();
if(str.Length > 50000)
    str = str.Remove(50000); // or Substring(0,50000)
var sb = new StringBuilder(str);
```

Comment: and safer, too.